# Scrape list of libraries using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the list of libraries from https://www.nypl.org/locations/list using the following code:

```
req = urllib2.Request('https://www.nypl.org/locations/list', headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
library = urllib2.urlopen( req ).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(library)
```

However, the soup object doesn't seem to contain all the elements and more importantly the list (i.e. tbody tag). Do I need to make an AJAX call to scrape the list ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: The page is dynamically generated. It's possible that an AJAX call is needed to scrape here. Either that, or use a browser type scraper, like Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the dynamic content by directly parsing the api which this app uses to load data
This is the endpoint

```
https://refinery.nypl.org/api/nypl/locations/v1.0/locations
```

Comment: I agree this is the best course, but then it's better if he uses the full API, is it not?

Comment: Yes, when api (not private api )is available  it doesn't make sense to scrape website.

Comment: @sugam thanks for the pointer. I will try through the APIs and hopefully get the required data. Will mark it as the answer once I get through it.